# CopyLocal = False for assemblies in GAC not working

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

According to [MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ez524kew%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

> By default, the CopyLocal property is set to False if the assembly or component is in the global assembly cache or is a framework component. Otherwise, the value is set to True. Project-to-project references are always set to True.

I'm not seeing this as being consistent. My server is 2008 R2 and I have a tool for viewing the GAC. I'm also just calling *gacutil.exe /l* in the VS command prompt. Some examples of CopyLocal still being set to True, even though the assembly is in the GAC:

- Microsoft.Data.Edm
- Microsoft.Data.OData
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
- Oracle.DataAccess (I installed Oracle 12c x86 ODP.NET)

There are many others. This project was started by using the default MVC template. There are others that are being set to false. Has anyone else seen this, or understands this behavior?
Thanks

Comment: There are two GACs, are you looking at the correct one?  Are you using the correct version of gacutil?  Why are you developing software on a server?

Comment: How do I tell which one I should be looking at? I assumed there was one GAC with many locations an assembly could reside. My team develops a wide range of applications...web, console, Biztalk, IBM MQ, etc... We basically develop on what we deploy to. Does that matter? Also using the VS 2013 console to run gacutil.

Comment: @HansPassant I did some more research and have found some of your older comments on other posts helpful. You meant 2 GAC's because of the framework version. That never occurred to me that it would be split up. This leads me to (I think) a better question, when I use gacutil, how do I tell which GAC I am pointed at?

Comment: Type "where gacutil.exe" and it will be obvious.

Comment: Sorry @HansPassant, I already knew which gacutil.exe I was using. I guess I didn't know that that was how you tell which GAC you were pointed to.

Comment: You should see more than one.  If you don't then you are using the wrong version of the Visual Studio Command Prompt.  This in general is a severe problem with what you posted so far, it doesn't give anybody a clue what you are actually doing.

Comment: @HansPassant, if you try it in VS 2013 (v12.0) you only get one gacutil. In other versions you see more than one yes. You obviously are very knowledgeable on the subject matter, but if the software is telling me there is one version, then your demeaning comments aren't helping. You could very easily replicate what I have done so far. Just create a new MVC app from the default template, and look at the CopyLocal settings for the references. All I'm asking is why are some true and others false, when they all appear in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

The CopyLocal is set when you initially add the assembly reference to the project. If you have created the project on a different computer, or on the same computer but when its state (e.g. GAC content) was different, it will still reflect the original setting. That may explain why CopyLocal does not match the expectations.